# How can I create a batch file to put file names in a .txt in a specific way

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch file or a script or any kind of automated process that will get all names of files in a certain folder and put them in a text file in a specific way. I haven't learned too much about batch files so I don't know how to create or edit files with them.

Example: 
files 54.png, 512.png, 762.png = new text file named textures.def containing the following:

```
texture 54    { pal 0  { file "highres/textures/54.png" } }
texture 512    { pal 0  { file "highres/textures/512.png" } }
texture 762    { pal 0  { file "highres/textures/762.png" } }
```

Comment: Execute from command prompt `dir /b > fnames.txt` rooted at the target directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a try for this batch script :

```bat
@echo off
Set "MyFolder=C:\temp\Test\"
Set "OutPutFile=textures.def"
Set "Ext=png"

>"%OutPutFile%" (
    @for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Dir /a-d /b "%MyFolder%\*.%Ext%"') do (
        echo texture %%~na    { pal 0  { file "highres/textures/%%a" } }
    )
)
pause
```